# Connect to Postgres from Python, without password

Tags: python, passwords, psycopg2, greenplum

Good day,

We have the following Python code that works from our production environment:

```
try:
    conn = psycopg2.connect(host=db_ip, port=db_port, database=db_name, user=db_user) 
    cur = conn.cursor()
    dataRows = cur.fetchall()
```

I need to port this to a new server and connect to a new database. In both cases the code runs from a different server to that what the database is on. The database name, username and password on the new database is the same as it was on the production database. The IP and port values are set dynamically for the new DB server.

On the new server I get the following error:

> **psycopg2.OperationalError: fe_sendauth: no password supplied**

What makes that the production environment does not require a password, and how can I mimic this configuration on the new server / environment?

Comment: The contents of [pg_hba.conf](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/auth-pg-hba-conf.html). Best guess, the first server has `trust` authentication set up and no password is needed, whereas the second server is requiring a password. Though if you are allowing remote logins `trust` is not safe at all.

Comment: Can you try first with psql instead of the Python script? This rules out any connection problem. On the server side you might see entries in the logfile.

Comment: @A.Scherbaum, JacquesB posted an answer(since deleted) that said changing the authentication method in `pg_hba.conf` solved the problem.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver, the reason I deleted my answer was that it did not work. I initially thought it did, but I ran an incorrect test. The code still prompts me for the DB password.

Comment: 1) What are the contents of the `pg_hba.conf` file for the new server and how does it differ from the production server? 2) Do you have a [pgpass](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-pgpass.html) file set up on the production server? Or the env variable `PGPASSWORD` per [Env Variables](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-envars.html).